# asp.net core tilde slash (~/) not resolving image path

Tags: html, css, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have some markup in my Index.cshtml view, which has an inline css style with the 
`background-image` property. When the page is rendered the correct path of the image is not being generated and the tilde remains in the url

HTML Markup:

The path that is used on the `img` tag works properly when the page is rendered, but the path in the `background-image` property displays like this and the image is not found

Rendered Markup:
[image]

```
<article class="card-item card-item-colored" style="background-image:url(~/build/images/11.jpg);">
                <img class="card-item-pic" src="/build/images/11.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="card-item-hover">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse-colored">View Demo</a>
                </div>
                <header class="card-item-caption">
                    <h4>Login Page</h4>
                </header>
            </article>
```

Comment: Can you not remove the tilde?

Comment: @wazz yes i could remove the tilde, but why doesn't the razor functionality ~/ work as expected?

Comment: Sry, I'm not too familiar with it. Is the styling part of razor syntax? I did some googling and it seems styles can be tricky. One link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351418/mvc-cannot-display-image-using-background-url-in-css-uses-bundling. Second-last answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821921/css-background-image-refuses-to-display-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @wazz yes using `@Url.Content()` does work. this styling is not in the css file. it's in the html file. I guess i will just use `@Url.Content()` until i find out why this is happening. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a style property, `url(...)` is a CSS function not a Razor method.

In the CSS `url(...)` function, start with a forward slash `/` not a tilda `~` to make a URI relative to the root of your site:

```
<article style="background-image:url(/build/images/11.jpg);">
```

The CSS 2.1 specification specifies this in section [4.3.4 URLs and URIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri) and refers to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986) for details, which states:

> A relative reference that begins with a single slash character is termed an absolute-path reference.

Answer (score 13):

The use of the tilde (~) in `@Url.Content()`, and elsewhere in Razor code, will be translated by ASP.NET to reference the root of the current application.

If you use the tilde directly in a string expression, such as within `background-image: url()` it is not interpreted (parsed) by ASP.NET, and so appears directly *as is* in the HTML or CSS that is output. This doesn't work because ~ is not a feature of HTML or CSS.