# a file with an html extension cannot be served in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have just created a new .net core 3.1 web project and I am able to successfully run it (obviously as one would expect)

[image]

but strangely when I add a partial tag helper in my `Index.cshtml` file to a html file that i know exists:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <partial name="~/PrerenderAssets/styles.html" />  @* <--------  this line*@ 
</div>
```

it renders an exception saying it cannot find it as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

This definitely use to work in a .net core 2.1 project I worked on before so after a couple hours researching I cannot seem to find what has changed in .net core 3.1 to cause this issue or is it that I am making a silly mistake somewhere?

you can replicate this issue by creating a new .net core 3.1 web project and creating a folder in the root with a html file it in and trying to render it in the `Index.cshtml` file.

could someone enlighten me here please? thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this explain it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526620/asp-net-core-tilde-slash-not-resolving-image-path

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I read those answers and understood what they where trying to explain but it doesn't say how it solves this problem at hand.  This exact line of code `<partial name="~/PrerenderAssets/styles.html" />` works in a .net core 2.1 project.

Comment: and using `Url.Content` as suggested in the linked answer results in the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> file cannot be found in .net core 3.1 with `<partial name="~/PrerenderAssets/styles.html" />`
>
> work in a .net core 2.1 project

I can reproduce same issue, and it seems that the [ViewEngine](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ViewEngines) would reply on build time compiled views (.cshtml files) in 3.0+, which cause the issue.

In your 3.1 project, please use `.cshtml` file  rather than rendering html file as partial view.

```
<partial name="~/PrerenderAssets/styles.cshtml"/>
```

Besides, you can refer to this github issue that discussed a similar issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17650#issuecomment-562671539

Comment: Thanks Fei, your help is very much appreciated!. I spent the entire day on Friday trying to figure out this issue but to no avail. I wish i could vote this answer *a lot more* than just once.