# Debuging Asp.net core web with IIs is different than direct browsing

Tags: debugging, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

it's my first question here so i'm very excited :).

I moved recently from programing mvc-5/6 to asp.net core.
Now, i noticed when i debug my website i have several options:

-IIS

-SolutionName via cmd deployment

-Browse with

The funny thing is that when i deploy my web with IIS (F5) the browser doesn't get all my css references (which does not effect few of my privately cssed elements). But when i deploy it by the other 2 options i mentioned earlier it does work.

Now I've been searching a bit around for an explanation for that and find none.
Due to my lack of understanding in IIS i assume the problem is somewhere there and here are the following 2 questions:

1) Why are there such distinctions?

2) Does it matter eventually if the IIS doesn't respond as i expected when other debugging methods does respond correctly?

Thanks you!!!

[A pic to show my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKGz8.png)

```
.banner {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 20%;
    min-width: 30%;
    background-image: url('/ProfilePic/Profile.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Would you please share us the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be careful here - **it definitely does matter** - as an answer for question 2.

When you switch from old MVC to core, you will realize that your "served" files go and lie in the wwwroot folder.

It is completely possible that you did not reference your *CSS* just right (as it differs from normal MVC's file structure). Also, be sure to use a relative path as opposed to an absolute one.

Have a look here:

**Correct:**

```
<link href="~/css/site-internal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Incorrect:**

```
<link href="~/wwwroot/css/site-internal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://localhost:5000/css/site-internal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Could be that your problem is unrelated, but it is something to watch out for none the less.

**EDIT**

Your CSS's should definitely be able to load without regard to whichever way you run the program.

As an aside - *the IIS option allows you to debug and step through your JS and could be quite useful.*

What you want to do here is go into your browser dev tools (F12 most of the time), and go see if your CSS gets resolved correctly - you can continue once you know what your problem is.

*Usually if something goes wrong in the process of loading CSS you wil get errors straight in the browser console*

**EDIT #2**

Upon further perusal of your problem statement - I think it might be that your CSS is loaded correctly but you've got a problem with that image URL.

Please check the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821921/css-background-image-refuses-to-display-in-asp-net-mvc)

The URL of the image inside a CSS file is relative to the path of the CSS file.

Therefore your solution will be something like this:

```
../ProfilePic/Profile.png
```

The `..` moves up one level.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited the post with picture and the css code inside.

Comment: Glad to help and welcome. Always remember to include as much info that is relevant as you can! Check out edit 2 for the solution I believe.

Comment: I did check, thanks!
Right now after playing around with the position of my css file (i put it directly in lib folder in wwwroot) and playing around while debuging and changing things everything is working good so far (maybe even a restart to VS did the job). 
Thank you very much for the good tips!

Comment: Because of lack of experience the issue was that i did not press ctr+f5 to re-deploy the website properly... I assume there are many things that could've been the problem in that case, so that was mine. But thank you again gents!

Comment: @ Terrance00, So you have resolved this issue by yourself, am I right? If so, you could post your solution as the answer and mark it. So it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the answer easily. Have a nice day:)